# pagination with flutter and supabase with bloc pattern

Tags: flutter, pagination, supabase, supabase-flutter

What is the best way to use pagination with flutter and Supabase and bloc pattern

I tried to use the range method in Supabase but it didn't work

I want the data not to be loaded all at once in the grid, but to be loaded while scrolling,
What is the best way to do That?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.